# Setting up federated trust between wso2 servers

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I'm trying to figure out how to get two wso2 identity servers to trust each other.

The wso2 documentation shows a great article about ***WHAT*** I want to set up here:
http://docs.wso2.org/display/IS450/Decentralized+Federated+SAML2+IdPs

but includes exactly 0 information about ***HOW*** to make it work!

Any help would be greatly apreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes... It has not been added to doc...  i am not sure about it.. However,  there is a blog post about [this](http://isharaaruna.blogspot.com/2013/10/federated-saml2-idp-with-wso2is.html). You can try out it.. I guess it may work.

Comment: I noticed that blog post says you need to use a beta version of Identity Server, Is this possible at all with version 4.5?

Comment: As i understood,  when user is directed to one IS server (foo),  then that IS server directed user to another IS (bar).  This foo IS server must create SAML request and do it..  I guess, in 450 you may need to write this logic as an authenticator and plug it with foo IS.  But  next release, you do not want to write it and plug it..  as it is already there.